# Proving that if $d(x, a) < \varepsilon$ for every $a \in A$, then $d(x, b) \geq \varepsilon$ for every $b \in X \setminus A$

Tags: metric-spaces

I want to prove the following result:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Then
>   $$\mathring E = \{x \in X \mid d(x, X \setminus E) > 0\}$$
>   where $d(x, A) = \inf\limits_{y \in A} d(x, y)$.

This is a part of my proof. But I'm not sure about a passage.

- $\mathring E \subseteq \{x \in X \mid d(x, X \setminus E) > 0\}$
  Let $x \in \mathring E$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \varepsilon) \subset E$.
  **We then have that**, for every $y \in X \setminus E$,
  $$d(x, y) \geq \varepsilon > 0.$$
  It follows that $d(x, X \setminus E) > 0$.

The other inclusion is much the same. The problem is that the bold passage seems so obvious, but I would like to prove it as well and I don't know how to do it.

How can I prove that if $d(x, a) < \varepsilon$ for every $a \in A$, then $d(x, b) \geq \varepsilon$ for every $b \in X \setminus A$?

Comment: $B(x, \varepsilon) \subset E\iff X\setminus E\subset X\setminus B(x,\varepsilon)\iff\forall y\in X\setminus E,\ldots$

Comment: If you found the answer, then might I suggest that you either self-answer the question, or ask @Did to turn his comment into an answer. Otherwise this question will  go into the unanswered queue.

Comment: @gebruiker Seems reasonable. I'll add an answer, and I'll be open to suggestions to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete proof for the first inclusion, with the hint from **@Did**. The other inclusion is really similar.

Let $x \in \mathring E$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $$B(x, \varepsilon) \subset E.$$
From that inclusion we deduce $X \setminus E \subset X \setminus B(x, \varepsilon)$. Then it necessarily follows that if $y \in X \setminus E$, it's also true that $y \in X \setminus B(x, \varepsilon)$. Since it's not true that $d(x, y) < \varepsilon$, it must be the case that $d(x, y) \geq \varepsilon > 0$.
We conclude that $d(x, X \setminus E) = \inf_{y \in X \setminus E} d(x, y) \geq \varepsilon > 0$.